# How to get IBM HTTP Server installation directory dynamically in linux, unix and AIX?

Tags: ibmhttpserver

` I tried echo ${SERVERROOT} in sh. I execute this script in desktop. It displays empty. How to get installation path dynamically?

Comment: Try this: `apxs -q exp_htdocsdir`

Comment: If you can find the right apxs, you already know where IBM HTTP Server is.

Comment: I think you post a command for AIX apxs -q . I need for linux also.. In linux how to get Installation directory of IBM HTTP Server dynamically? @LorinczyZsigmond

Comment: Not really, program `apxs` is part of Apache (IBM HTTP server is a re-branded Apache).

Answer (score 1):

Since there could be multiple installations of multiple releases, to reliably find them you'd need to parse (for 8.0 and later) /var/ibm/InstallationManager/installed.xml

Or, sort this out once and set an environment variable or symlink on the system.